# Chrome shows wrong time zone

Tags: google-chrome, timezone

In Windows my time zone is set to UTC+2:00 Jerusalem

But several websites think I'm in UTC. And I see that Chrome reports my timezone as UTC. When I try this in my console

```
Intl.DateTimeFormat().resolvedOptions().timeZone
```

I get "UTC"

Though I can't for the life of me find any setting in Chrome that keeps it's own timezone.

I'm using WIndows 10. Here's the `navigator.userAgent`

```
"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.88 Safari/537.36"
```

If I run `tzutil /g` in the command line, I get:

```
Israel Standard Time
```

There are extensions that let me change the timezone. But I'd rather solve the issue. So I can help other clients with similar issues.

**UPDATE**

It seems that this isssue happens only in pages run from visual studio via `IIS`. If I check the timezone in regular gmail or wikipedia etc then the tiemzone is correct.

But in a browser that was opened from `VS`, when running my asp.net site, the timezone always shows UTC. Even if in said browser I will open wikipedia. Th browser somehow gets "set" to utc.

Where can this be fixed?

Thanks!

Comment: Hi.  I tried, but I am unable to reproduce this.  Which version of Windows are you running?  Have you run all Windows Updates?  Can you supply the value of `navigator.userAgent` from the browser please?  Also can you supply the value of `tzutil /g` from the Windows command line?  Thanks.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for taking an interest. I added the relevant information to the post. I'd love to hear what's wrong. Thanks!

Comment: Hmmm..  That all looks fine.  You shouldn't be getting UTC from the first one.  I have the same versions and it works fine for me.  Something else is at play - maybe an extension you installed, or maybe your clock is not synchronized correctly, not sure.   Anyway, since there's nothing to offer from a programming perspective, I suggest you post about this on [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/) and also file a bug/support request with Google [here](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95315). Include screenshots where you can.  Good luck! :)

Comment: Thanks. Done both. we'll wait and see :-)

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65912684/lastest-chrome-gets-a-wrong-timezone-in-console - this is a known bug in Chrome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try reseting your time zone again in Windows.
I had this issue a few days ago as well. What I did was to set the time zone to something else, apply, then back to the correct one and apply.

Comment: Consider adding some reasoning behind your answer.

Comment: Thanks. I see google also gives this solution here https://support.google.com/chrome/thread/94734423/chrome-is-16-hours-behind-computer-s-time?hl=en&msgid=95579769