# Lastest Chrome gets a wrong timezone in Console

Tags: google-chrome

Today I updated my computer Chrome browser to the latest version (version 88.0.4324.104 (official version) (64-bit)). Then I entered the command to print the date and time in Chrome's Console, but it showed the wrong time zone. My system time and the time of the Firefox browser are correct. What is the reason for this and how to solve it?

**Chrome Wrong Timezone info**
[image: chrome console output]
**Firefox Correct Timezone info**
[image: Firefox console output]
**My Computer System Timezone Settings**
[image: system timezone]
[image: system timezone in dos]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Chrome 88 incorrect time zone sign](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65912692/chrome-88-incorrect-time-zone-sign)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Same happening here. Looks like Chrome doesn't know hot to handle with DST off. Until they don't provide a patch, turn DST on or just choose another city in the same time zone but different country.

Comment: Couldn't test, but maybe forcing to remove _dstoff with command `tzutil /s "China Standard Time"` may solve it.

Comment: In Brazil, it worked changing time zone from Brasilia or Sao Paulo to **Salvador**.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the timezone on Windows to another city / gmt setting, saving and then changing back.

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it

Comment: doesn't fix it from my end. when I change to a timezone (let's say with offset GMT-5), the chrome browser flips the sign and reports GMT+5. happens with any tz i switch to. however, flipping on automatic DST seems to help

Answer (score 1):

Same for me. After updating chrome to the latest version 88.0.4324.150 , the bug is fixed.

Comment: I was at 88.0.4324.96 and updating to 88.0.4324.152 solved the issue for me. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Friends,
Refer the problem to the Bug sector of the Chromium project that is the maintainer of google chormium, who can comment, list the bug code, warn about the DST (time zone), and also about the location, thank you for the strength.

[link about the bug in the chromium project](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1171740)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**Also reported here.**
https://piunikaweb.com/2021/01/29/google-chrome-88-incorrect-time-stamp-glitch-official-fix-coming-soon/

**Solution**
https://support.google.com/chrome/thread/94734423?hl=en&msgid=95579769

**Bug Tracker**
https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1168614