# Chrome 88 incorrect time zone sign

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

Starting from about 20.01.2021, after the Chrome update to version 88.0, the time zone incorrectly processed in applications. When calling the Date() function, the time zone has a different sign (-07:00 instead of +07:00):
[image: Incorrect time zone sign]
[image: System time zone]

After changing the time zone in the system and restarting the browser, the time zone is picked up correctly. After restarting the operating system, the problem returns. The problem is observed on Windows 7 and Windows 10. There is no such error in the Mozilla Firefox browser. Has anyone encountered the same problem and how to solve it?

Comment: I found an [issue](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1168528) in the Chrome issue tracker on this problem.

Answer (score 3):

This is indeed [issue 1168528 in Chromium](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1168528) (bug in Chrome 88 stable), you are correct.

Root cause: A bug in the ICU library, as used by Chrome et al, for when Automatic DST is OFF in Windows. See [comments from an ICU developer on ICU PR 1543](https://github.com/unicode-org/icu/pull/1543).

Workaround: Affected users can change their Windows timezone settings to a completely different TZ, then change it back the original. We asked users to restart the browser afterwards & try using the web application again, and the problem was corrected. (I don't think they changed their Auto DST settings, and yet the problem was fixed...)

The characteristic feature of the bug is the e.g. GMT-7 instead of GMT+7.

Answer (score -1):

tzutil /s "E. South America Standard Time"
Nota: este comando deve estar de acordo com o fuso horário do usuário.

Comment: Hey Luiz, welcome to Stack Overflow! Please provide an answer in the English language, as this is the internationally accepted language we use on this platform.